# How do I get the maximum of an ArrayType of MapTypes using Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark DataFrame:

```
df = sql.createDataFrame([
        (1, [
                {'name': 'john', 'score': '0.8'},
                {'name': 'johnson', 'score': '0.9'},
            ]),
        (2, [
                {'name': 'jane', 'score': '0.9'},
                {'name': 'janine', 'score': '0.4'},
            ]),
        (3, [
                {'name': 'sarah', 'score': '0.2'},
                {'name': 'sara', 'score': '0.9'},
            ]),
    ], schema=['id', 'names'])
```

Spark correctly infers the schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

For each row, I want to select the name with the highest score. I can do this using a Python UDF as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def top_name(names):
    return sorted(names, key=lambda d: d['score'], reverse=True)[0]['name']

top_name_udf = F.udf(top_name, T.StringType())

df.withColumn('top_name', top_name_udf('names')) \
    .select('id', 'top_name') \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

As desired, you get:

```
+---+--------+
|id |top_name|
+---+--------+
|1  |johnson |
|2  |jane    |
|3  |sara    |
+---+--------+
```

How can I do this using Spark SQL? Is it possible to do it *without* a Python UDF so that the data isn't serialised between Python and Java?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately, I'm running Spark 1.5 and can't use [`registerJavaFunction`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=registerjavafunction#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerJavaFunction) in Spark 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sqlContext.registerFunction` method to register your function (not udf) to sql. Also register your df as a sql table.

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "names_df")

sqlContext.registerFunction("top_name", top_name,T.StringType())

sqlContext.sql("SELECT top_name(names) as top_name from names_df").collect()

> [Row(top_name=u'johnson'), Row(top_name=u'jane'), Row(top_name=u'sara')]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. However, is it possible to do it _without_ a Python UDF and use pure SQL instead? I'd like to avoid the serialisation between Python and Java.

Unfortunately I'm on Spark 1.5 and don't have access to [`registerJavaFunction`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=registerjava#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerJavaFunction) to register a Scala/Java UDF.

Comment: Can you use regular sql?   `sqlcontext.sql( "SELECT FIRST(name) as top_names
FROM  df
GROUP BY score
ORDER BY score DESC;" )`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work. The only the table columns are available to the group by. I don't think it's possible to do it, at least in this version of Spark.